# Insert count from 2 diff tables

Tags: hive

I want to insert in a table multiple counts I mean count all from cars and trucks and insert the result in a row in a table.

```
insert into table result(A,B)
select r1,r2 from(
select count(*) from trucks where fecha='X' and name like '%X%' and  name not like '%X%' as r1,
select count(*) from cars where fecha='X' and name like '%X%' and  name not like '%X%' as r2
) 
;
```

I tried that but dont work... I do not know why...

I just discover I am using a hive enviroment and subqueries are not supported

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing your two subqueries with parentheses like this:

```
INSERT INTO table result(A, B)
VALUES (
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM trucks
        WHERE fecha='X' AND name LIKE '%X%' AND name NOT LIKE '%X%'
    ),
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM cars
        WHERE fecha='X' AND name LIKE '%X%' AND name NOT LIKE '%X%'
    )
);
```

Comment: Error gives to me:  cannot recognize input near 'select' 'count' '(' in expression specification,but I thin that is correct

Comment: Strange...this query should be working with no issues.  Is `table` either `trucks` or `cars`?  You can't use the table into which you are inserting in the subquery.

Comment: No no result is a new table with two columns A and B and thats why I dont get why nothing work, theoretically it is an easy query

Answer (score 0):

Try this like that :-

```
  INSERT INTO destination_table ( 
          Field_1, 
          Field_2 
          ) 
    SELECT Field_1, 
          Field_2  
          FROM source_table;
```

Comment: Does not work source table is different for each field